# Simple edge detection method Java

Tags: java, pixel

I am working on a method in Java to do some simple edge detection.  I want to take the difference of two color intensities one at a pixel and the other at the pixel directly below it.  The picture that I am using is being colored black no matter what threshold I put in for the method.  I am not sure if my current method is just not computing what I need it to but I am at a loss what i should be tracing to find the issue.

Here is my method thus far:

```
public void edgeDetection(double threshold)
{

  Color white = new Color(1,1,1);
  Color black = new Color(0,0,0);

  Pixel topPixel = null;
  Pixel lowerPixel = null;

  double topIntensity;
  double lowerIntensity;

  for(int y = 0; y < this.getHeight()-1; y++){
    for(int x = 0; x < this.getWidth(); x++){

      topPixel = this.getPixel(x,y);
      lowerPixel = this.getPixel(x,y+1);

      topIntensity =  (topPixel.getRed() + topPixel.getGreen() + topPixel.getBlue()) / 3;
      lowerIntensity =  (lowerPixel.getRed() + lowerPixel.getGreen() + lowerPixel.getBlue()) / 3;

      if(Math.abs(topIntensity - lowerIntensity) < threshold)
        topPixel.setColor(white);
      else
        topPixel.setColor(black);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`new Color(1,1,1)` calls the `Color(int,int,int)` constructor of `Color` which takes values between 0 and 255. So your `Color white` is still basically black (well, very dark grey, but not enough to notice).

If you want to use the `Color(float,float,float)` constructor, you need float literals:

```
Color white = new Color(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f);
```

Comment: Thank you, I miss read the documentation for the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void edgeDetection(int edgeDist)
  {
Pixel leftPixel = null;
Pixel rightPixel = null;
Pixel bottomPixel=null;
Pixel[][] pixels = this.getPixels2D();
Color rightColor = null;
boolean black;
for (int row = 0; row < pixels.length; row++)
{
  for (int col = 0; 
       col < pixels[0].length; col++)
  {
    black=false;
    leftPixel = pixels[row][col];
    if (col<pixels[0].length-1)
    {
      rightPixel = pixels[row][col+1];
      rightColor = rightPixel.getColor();
      if (leftPixel.colorDistance(rightColor) > 
          edgeDist)
        black=true;
    }
    if (row<pixels.length-1)
    {
      bottomPixel =pixels[row+1][col];
      if (leftPixel.colorDistance(bottomPixel.getColor())>edgeDist)
        black=true;

    }
    if (black)
      leftPixel.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    else
      leftPixel.setColor(Color.WHITE);
  }
}
```

}